Animated SVG component doesn't show up in mobile view
Using Next.js v.14.1 and I'm having issues with this component:
"use client";
import "./rotating-text.css";

const RotatingText = () => {
  return (
    <div className="rounded-text rotating absolute inset-0 flex justify-center items-center">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
        <path
          id="textPath"
          d="M 85,0 A 85,85 0 0 1 -85,0 A 85,85 0 0 1 85,0"
          transform="translate(100,100)"
          fill="none"
        ></path>
        <g fontSize="1.156rem">
          <text textAnchor="start">
            <textPath href="#textPath" startOffset="0%">
              - Andre Castillon - Web Developer - UX / UI Designer
            </textPath>
          </text>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RotatingText;

Here's the CSS aswell:
@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.rotating {
  animation: rotating 18s linear infinite;
}

.rounded-text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  fill: #fbfbfb;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #151419;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .rotating {
    animation-duration: 36s; /* Slower rotation on smaller screens */
  }
  .rounded-text {
    transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Further adjust rotation for mobile */
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #151419; /* Adjusted shadow for better contrast */
  }
}

Lastly, where the component is being used on the home page:
"use client";
import Image from "next/image";
import portrait from "/public/images/Portrait-BW.png";
import RotatingText from "@/components/rotating-text/RotatingText";
import Cursor from "@/components/Cursor";
import { useState } from "react";
import RippleButton from "@/components/ripple-button/RippleButton";
import Contact from "@/components/contact/Contact";

export default function Home() {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen mx-auto px-6 items-center flex-col bg-dark-void">
      <div
        onMouseOver={() => {
          setIsActive(true);
        }}
        onMouseLeave={() => {
          setIsActive(false);
        }}
        className="my-14 relative z-10"
      >
        <Image
          src={portrait}
          width={700}
          height={700}
          alt="Picture of the author"
          quality={100}
          priority={true}
          className="rounded-full"
        />
        <RotatingText />
      </div>

      <div className="z-10">
        <RippleButton />
      </div>

      <div className="z-10">
        <Contact />
      </div>

      <Cursor isActive={isActive} />
    </main>
  );
}

The component renders fine in desktop and when changing dimensions it scales fine. However, I just can't for the life of me figure out why the animated SVG component doesn't show up in mobile view and how to fix this.
I tried using ChatGPT and Phind, along with using a CSS @media rule.
Anything is greatly appreciated thanks!

Could you be more explicit in what you mean by "mobile view" please? The code seems to work as expected in Stackblitz.

@Wongjn mobile view meaning the component doesnt show up on a iphone.
